# Где живет EditBin.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Пытаюсь выполнить в Post -Build event такую команду:

`"$(DevEnvDir)..\..\vc\bin\EditBin.exe" "$(TargetPath)"  /LARGEADDRESSAWARE` , но ловлю ошибку с кодом 3.

Стоит Visual Studio 2017.

Или эта штука вообще не нужна, если я собираю под Any Cpu?

Просто, решение в TFS в таком виде лежала.

Comment: Вроде, Large Address Aware устанавливается флажком в свойствах проекта...

Comment: У меня файл `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\editbin.exe` есть, он как раз совпадает с тем, что у вас прописано.

Comment: @VladD, Что-то у меня по этому пути его нет. Может быть что-то нужно поставить?Что вообще дает эта директива? Собирая приложение под х32, оно сможет использовать адресное пространство свыше 2гб?

Comment: Да, есть подозрение, что при использовании новых версий студии приложения AnyCPU Prefer 32bit автоматически являются LARGEADDRESSAWARE (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/812e37a2-b3a9-4295-8a5a-aafc2217d1cf/when-to-compile-with-any-cpu-and-when-compile-x86-and-x64-separately?forum=csharpgeneral) Вы можете проверить это на практике с помощью команды `dumpbin /headers`

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: Почему не как ответ? Это по сути решает проблему ТС.

Answer (score 4):

Похожий вопрос задавали на английском Stack Overflow: [vsvars32.bat in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805662).

В Visual Studio 2017 изменился не только стандартный путь по которому всегда можно было найти devenv.exe (*"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio %version%\Common7\IDE"*), но в том числе и путь к утилитам.

В частности, путь к утилите editbin.exe будет примерно таким: *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx86\x64\editbin.exe"*. В этом пути несколько переменных, которые будут отличатся в зависимости от версии и редакции Visual Studio: **2017**, **Professional**, и **14.14.26428**. Кроме этого, папки **Hostx86** и **x64** так же могут быть заменены на **Hostx64** и **x86**, соответственно.

Таким образом, Post-build event команда может быть вот такой: *$(DevEnvDir)....\vc\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx86\x86\editbin.exe" "$(TargetPath)"  /LARGEADDRESSAWARE*

Возможно, должны быть специальные макросы или переменные окружения, позволяющие задать корректный путь не вникая в значение переменных, но среди макросов похожих путей я не нашел, равно как и среди переменых которые выводит команда SET.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу @Uranus, у меня нужный файл нашёлся тут:

```
"$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86)\editbin.exe"
```

Однако, эта переменная доступна при построении проектов на C++, но не C#.

Comment: Если не секрет, а что дает вообще LARGEADDRESSAWARE ? Типа будучи собранной под X32, она сможет работать с адресным пространством Х64? Или этот параметр вообще излишен и равен AnyCpu?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Вот немного по теме: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040812-00/?p=38183. Оно говорит, что в программе адресная арифметика не исходит из неявного предположения, что все указатели одного знака. Это существенно лишь для 32-битных программ, которые запускаются под Windows, которая запущена с ключом `/3GB` (то есть, в которой адресное пространство между юзермодом и ядром делится не как 2Гб/2Гб, а как 3Гб/1Гб).

Comment: @iluxa1810: И это позволяет Windows давать программе 3 Гб адресного пространства, а не 2.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с Visual Studio 2015, приложения, собранные в режиме "AnyCPU Prefer 32bit" автоматически являются LARGEADDRESSAWARE, поэтому нет необходимости добавлять этот параметр с помощью editbin. Это изменение не документировано, но упомянуто во многих местах на форумах, например [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/812e37a2-b3a9-4295-8a5a-aafc2217d1cf/when-to-compile-with-any-cpu-and-when-compile-x86-and-x64-separately?forum=csharpgeneral).

Для справки, пометка EXE-файла LARGEADDRESSAWARE дает:

- На 32-битной ОС без установленного параметра загрузки /3GB - ноль эффекта
- На 32-битной ОС с установленным параметром загрузки /3GB - увеличение максимального адресного пространства с 2 Гб до 3 Гб
- На 64-битной ОС - увеличение максимального адресного пространства с 2 Гб до 4 Гб

Answer (score 0):

В VS2019 Community пришлось доставить компонентов, чтобы editbin появился:
[image: Компоненты для editbin]

После установки editbin появился в папке:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx64\x64